# How do I connect iOS app with SQL database?

Tags: ios, swift, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an iOS application that sends JSON data to an SQLAlchemy database using flask. I'm fairly new to this, so I'm probably making some obvious mistakes. I'm getting an error on the swift side when I run the application saying

**"Could not connect to server"**

This is my Swift code:

```
enum APIError: Error {
case responseProblem
case decodingProblem
case encodingProblem } 

struct APIRequest {
let resourceURL: URL

init() {
    let resourceString =  "http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example"
    guard let resourceURL = URL(string: resourceString) else {fatalError()}
    
    self.resourceURL = resourceURL
}

func save (_ dataToSave:String, completion: @escaping(Result<Any, APIError>) -> Void) {
    
    do{
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: resourceURL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(dataToSave)
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, _ in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let jsonData = data else {
                completion(.failure(.responseProblem))
                return
            }
            do {
                let GPSData = try JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: jsonData)
                completion(.success(GPSData))
            }catch{
                completion(.failure(.decodingProblem))
            }
            
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }catch{
        completion(.failure(.encodingProblem))
    }
}
}
```

And this is my Python code for the database:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///data.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Connection success"

@app.route('/json-example', methods=['POST'])
def json_example():
    request_data = request.get_json()

    lattitude = None
    longitude = None

if request_data:
    if 'lattitude' in request_data:
        lattitude = request_data['lattitude']

    if 'longitude' in request_data:
        longitude = request_data['longitude']


return "connected"
       
       
class GPS(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'GPS Coordinates'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float)
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"GPS('{self.longitude}', '{self.latitude}')"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you running the app?  On a simulator or on a device?  You have specified `localhost` (127.0.0.1) as the server address.  If you are running on a simulator, is your server running on the same Mac?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Paulw11 . I'm running the app on a device.

Comment: Then 127.0.0.1 won't work - You need the IP address of the computer that is running your server.  127.0.0.1 is "this device" - the device running your app.  Your server isn't there

Comment: Also, if you use `http` rather than `https`, make sure to set the “App Transport Security” setting in your `Info.plist` to allow arbitrary URLs. By default, iOS will require secure `https` connections.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 that did it! So obvious too